# background coverage in css3 & html5

Tags: html, css, background

I cannot get a gradient .jpg image (created in PhotoShop) to cover the entire page using css3 & html5. I have read and tried everything I could find with either no effect, or the 'fix' removed the background image completely. Here is the code, I've tried so many different solutions, including w3schools.com, that I'm probably missing the obvious  (I hope):

```
@charset "UTF-8";  
#main_container {   
display: block;     
clear: both;    
overflow: hidden;   
width: 960px;   
height: 100%;   
margin-right: auto;     
margin-left: auto;  
box-shadow: 0px 5px 10x 0px #362819;    
background:#738A7A;     
text-align: justify;    
text-align: left;   
border: 5px double #99AFA3; 
} 
body {  
font-family:Tahoma,"Century Gothic","Lucida Grande";    
font-size: 1.1em;   
font-weight:bold;   
line-height:1.5em;  
padding:0px;    
margin-bottom:15px;     
background-color: #587056;  
background-image: url('img/bkg.jpg');   
background-size:cover; 
}  
#header {   
text-align: center;     
width: 960px; 
} 
#container {    
line-height: 1.5em;     
text-align:left;    
color: #331100;     
border: 4px ridge #587056;  
padding: 8px;   
margin: 8px;    
width: 60%;     
float: left; 
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to apply the background to the `html` element, or add `height:100%` to your `body` (however the latter case will only work properly if you also have `margin:0` there)

Comment: Thank you, I tried adding "margin:0px; height:100%;" with no effect, to the Css

Comment: I just tried adding <body style="background-image:url('img/bkg.jpg')"> to the html5, deleted the background code in css, no effect. At this point all I can think of is to make the image longer, but I'd really rather it stretch, and get it done in Css. Also tried adding overflow:"hidden"; also with no effect.

Comment: it is fixed but am not sure why:#main_container {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 960px;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border: 5px double #99AFA3;
 background: #738A7A;
 text-align: justify;
}
body {
 font-family: Tahoma,"Century Gothic","Lucida Grande";
 font-size: 1.1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 1.5em;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 background-color: #587056;
 background-image: url('img/bkg.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}